# Scala - how to use foreach loop in for comprehension block?

Tags: scala, scala-cats, for-comprehension

I have a simple code:

```
 override def createContributorsList(url: String, params: String): F[List[Contributor]] = getContributorsFromClient(url, params).fold[List[Contributor]](_ => List(), res => res)

 override def createReposList(organization: String, params: String): F[List[GitRepository]] = getReposFromClient(organization, params).fold[List[GitRepository]](_ => List(), res => res)
```

This code return list of repositories from github and list of contributions. But now I need to call `createContributorsList` for every repository I found by `createReposList`. I have done a `for comprehension` block:

```
val stats = new StatisticsRepository[IO](new GitHttpClient[IO])
val res = for {
    repos <- stats.createReposList("github", "")
  } yield repos
```

It works fine, it found repositories for given organization (github). So I tried do it like this:

```
val res = for {
    repos <- stats.createReposList("github", "")
    list = repos.foreach(repo => stats.createContributorsList(repo.contributors_url, ""))
  } yield (repos, list)
```

But `list` is always empty. I don't know how I could do this without `for comprehension`, because I operate here on `Monads` like `IO`. How I should create a code to loop over every repo from `repos` and call `stats.createContributorsList` on everyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `flatTraverse`

```
import cats.syntax.flatMap._
import cats.syntax.functor._
import cats.syntax.traverse._
import cats.instances.list._

val res: F[(List[GitRepository], List[Contributor])] = for {
  repos <- stats.createReposList("github", "")
  list <- repos.flatTraverse(repo => stats.createContributorsList(repo.contributors_url, ""))
} yield (repos, list)
```

`foreach` return `Unit` so that's not what you need.

Comment: Is it possible to return simple ` List[Contributor]` instead of `F[...]`? The problem is when I want to run it I always need to use `unsafeRunSync` to get list. Or how I can get `A` from `F[A]`?

Comment: You shouldn't want to get `A` from `F[A]`. As soon as you get into monad you continue to work with monad. This is common for all monads (Option, Future, IO...). For example with for-compehensions like `for { a <- ... : F[A]; ...` Normally you run `unsafeRunSync` once, at the very end.

Comment: `list` inside `list <- repos.flatTraverse...` has type `List[Contributor]`.